# DAX for value depending upon dynamic time series filter

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax, measure, slicers

[image]Can anyone help in writing Power BI DAX Measure for returning col value based upon certain date filter value from a slicer
The expected value should be dynamic based upon the selected filter date

for ex:

In the Given Table
[image: Date Tag 05/31/2000 A 09/30/2000 A 01/02/2001 C 04/28/2001 B]

Selected Slicer Filter:
Date Filter  >> **Qtr 1'2001**

Expected Result
[image]
**Date        Tag
05/31/2000  C
09/30/2000  C
01/02/2001  C**

But when the filter is updated:
Selected Slicer Filter:
Date Filter  >> **Qtr 2'2001**

Expected Result
[image]
**Date         Tag
05/31/2000  B
09/30/2000  B
01/02/2001  B
04/28/2001  B**

I tried this, This doesn't returned any value

Expected Result = VAR= SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Datefilter')
VAR Tag= LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Tag], 'Table'[Date], SelectedDate)
RETURN
Tag

Comment: I would suggest you share the small diagram of your model and try to format the sample/output a little better.

Comment: @mxix pls check i have uploaded image links

for full diagram look the very first image link uploaded

Comment: Create a disconnected table with the dates and use that one on the Slicer. That way the slicer does not filter the table and you can do what you want